# how can i test a computed property in vuejs using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

im still new with unit testing and i want to test if the a linked button is displayed when the `isLinkPresent` computed property return the link of the image and is not empty of this component :

```
    <template lang="pug">
    .merchandising_image_title
  .image(:style="`background-image: url('${imageTitle.image}');`" )
  .panel
    .top
      h2 {{imageTitle.top_title}}
      .line
    .center
      h1 {{imageTitle.center_title}}
    .bottom(v-if="isLinkPresent")
      a.btn.round( target='_blank' :href='imageTitle.link') Notify Me By Email
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'MerchandisingImageTitle',
      props: {
        imageTitle: Object
      },
      computed:{
        isLinkPresent(){
          return this.imageTitle.link && this.imageTitle.link !== ''
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

i have tried to test it like this by overwriting the computed property :

```
    it("renders linked button when image title has a link and is not empty", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(ImageTitle, {
    propsData: {
      imageTitle: Object
    },
    computed: {
      isLinkPresent() {
        return this.imageTitle.link && this.imageTitle.link !== "";
      }
    }
  });
  expect(wrapper.find("a").isVisible()).toBe(true);
});
```

but it gave me this error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: find did not return a, cannot call isVisible() on empty Wrapper

  13 |     }
  14 |   });
> 15 |   expect(wrapper.find("a").isVisible()).toBe(true);
     |                            ^
  16 | });
```

im not sure what am i doing wrong, any help would be appreciated

edit : okay so i realised i didnt pass the propsData correctly so i changed it to `propsData: { imageTitle: { imageTitleData: { image: "", top_title: "", center_title: "", link: ""}}}` and do `expect(wrapper.find(".bottom").exists()).toBe(true)` as that isVisible() is used mostly in v-show but still getting this error : `
    renders linked button when image title has a link and is not empty

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      20 |     }
      21 |   });
    > 22 |   expect(wrapper.find(".bottom").exists()).toBe(true);
         |                                            ^
      23 | });
      24 |`
```

Comment: What’s `ImageTitle`?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards  it's a prop that im passing it as an object in the component like so : `MerchandisingImageTitle(:imageTitle="imageTitleData")` knowing that `imageTitleData` is an object : `imageTitleData: {
        image: '',
        top_title: '',
        center_title: '',
        link: ''
      } `

Comment: What is the exact error you say you are still getting?

Comment: I mean in your tests what does `ImageTitle` refer to, not `imageTitle`?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards yes it refers to the imageTitle, please take a look at the edit i made above

Comment: This line here: `const wrapper = mount(ImageTitle, {` – what is `ImageTitle`? Where is that defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would start first by mounting the component and passing the right props to cover your use case

```
let wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
   propsData: {
     imageTitle: {
       link: 'https://google.com'
     }
   }
});
```

Then you'd check that the link is rendered as expected. You could either use `exists` or `findAll` and check the wrapper count.

`expect(wrapper.find('.bottom a').exists()).toBe(true)`
or

`expect(wrapper.findAll('.bottom a').length).toEqual(1)`

PS: Personal opinion but imho `imageTitle` should be named to something more intuitive like `imageData`.
Also would be even greater to pass these as individual props. E.g

`<my-component link="" src="" top_title="" center_title=""`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! it took me 24h to realise i wasn't passing the right props, as for the code it's not me who wrote it, im just doing the unit tests. thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

There is also the option of testing the property directly on the view model (`vm`, see [Vue2 view instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance)) that the wrapper provides.

```
expect(wrapper.vm.isLinkPresent).toBe(true)
```